# Showing text in below of image in asp.net menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I have tried to show the menu name below of menu icon,. but I don't know how to do that.

**My ASPX Code**

```
  <asp:menu runat="server" ItemWrap="true" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Admin.png" Selectable="true" Text="System" /> 
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/user.png" Selectable="true" Text="User" />
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/cut.png" Selectable="true" Text="Cut" />
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-copy.png" Selectable="true" Text="Copy" />                             
            </Items>
        </asp:menu>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: where is you aspx code.i dont see anywhere. ?@Sagotharan

Comment: now i update it sir. while put code mark unfortunate it disable.

Comment: @pravprab this link not help me, i have tried but menu look like Orientation vertical position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try putting `<br>` tag while setting Text to menu Item .
Then the menu will be

```
<asp:Menu runat="server" ItemWrap="true" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Admin.png" Selectable="true" Text="<br> System" />
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/user.png" Selectable="true" Text="<br> User" />
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/cut.png" Selectable="true" Text="<br> Cut" />
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-copy.png" Selectable="true" Text="<br> Copy" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```